# Trouble Installing XCode 10 beta 4

Tags: macos, terminal, install, xcode, mojave

After installing MacOS Mojave Beta, I ran into some trouble installing Xcode 10 beta 4. I need the latest version of Xcode to use common tools like `npm`, `node`, `yarn`, etc. 
After I found the install page and waited a very long time, I got `Xcode_10_beta_4.xip` from the Apple downloads page. Upon trying to unzip this `xip` folder, I get: 
`Xcode_10_beta_4.xip.cpgz` 
When trying to unzip THAT I get...
`Xcode_10_beta_4 2.xip`, etc.

The folder won't unzip and I need suggestions on how to get this installed.
Thanks in advance to anyone that knows a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was corrupted, that’s why it was opening weird. Because of my slow download speeds, and continual resumes when it kept pausing the download... it got corrupted. After finding a coffee shop with some good download speeds I tried again and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because .xip is not .zip. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414645/how-to-extract-xip-archive-using-command-line

You can use

```
xip -x <path/to/archive.xip>
```

I use https://github.com/danzimm/xip_extract since it gives a progress indicator.

Comment: I think this will work! Right now the file says it’s corrupted but I’ll try downloading it again and unxip it this way.

Comment: I can't remember if I've ever had issues with `xip -x`, but `xip_extract` definitely works every time for me.